# Decimal return string in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a field Decimal like this

```
 /**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="foo", type="decimal", precision=0, scale=2, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
private $foo;
```

When I use `getFoo()` or `QueryBuilder` my value is "159.79" instead of 159.79.
How can I get the correct type?

Comment: You can use `float` column type or to overwrite the `DecimalType` dbal type and `round` its value when `convertToPHPValue()`. https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Types/DecimalType.php#L52

Comment: How to build a custom mapping DBAL type http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types

Comment: @yceruto Note that, when using the "float", it will work only with some locales (the ones that use the decimal point as separator): https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.11/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types

That might effectively make the "float" unusable in many cases, with intl-ized applications

Answer (score 12):

Even though you have declared it as a decimal in your Doctrine annotation, when it is retrived PHP will treat it as a string.
[Reference here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#decimal).

> Values retrieved from the database are always converted to PHP’s
> string type or null if no data is present.

You could change the getter to cast as a float and then return.
E.g.

```
public function getFoo()
{
    return (float) $this->foo;
}
```

or

```
public function getFoo()
{
    return floatval($this->foo);
}
```

Look at [Type Juggling](https://www.php.net/language.types.type-juggling) for more info.
More info on `floatVal()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)

Comment: yes, but if I use querybuilder I don't use getFoo()

Answer (score 0):

Type your property to float and it should auto-cast it when you fetch the entity:

```php
/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="foo", type="decimal", precision=0, scale=2, nullable=false, unique=false)
 */
private float $foo;
```